# A likelihood problem with a biased coin

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to build up my intuition about likelihood and came up with the most general problem I could think up.

Suppose $m$ people flip an unfair coin $k$ times and $Z_i$ is the number of people who landed $i$ heads where $i\in{0,1,...,k}$. Would the likelihood $l(Z_0,Z_1,...,Z_k|p)$ be computed as:

$l(Z_0,Z_1,...,Z_k|p)=\Pi_{i=0}^k l(Z_i|p)=\Pi_{i=0}^k {km \choose iZ_i} p^{iZ_i}(1-p)^{km - iZ_i}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a multinomial factor in front representing the permutations of the people who got the various numbers of heads. Then the per-factor exponent sum of $p$ and $1-p$ should equal $Z_ik$ since that is the total number of coins flipped by the relevant people. The correct likelihood is
$$\binom m{Z_0,\dots,Z_k}\prod_{i=0}^k\left(\binom kip^i(1-p)^{k-i}\right)^{Z_i}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the exponent be $kZ_i$ rather than $Z_i$?

Comment: @darzan False. The $k$ part is inside the brackets (in the binomial pmf). The binomial pmf represents the probability of some fixed person getting $i$ heads.

Comment: @darzan Indeed the whole thing may be viewed as a multinomial distribution on the $Z_i$ with probabilities corresponding to the binomial distribution $B(k,i)$. Hence the stated form.

Comment: You need the $\binom m{Z_0,\dots,Z_k}$ for this to be the probability $\mathbb P(Z_0,Z_1,\ldots,Z_k\mid p)$, but I would have thought that once you are talking about likelihood $l(p\mid Z_0,Z_1,\ldots,Z_k)$ then it is not necessary (likelihoods are only meaningful up to proportionality, and should not be affected by whether you record the $m$ results in order or not)